# How not to save passwords and sensitive data in Quicksilver/Alfred clipboard history plugin?

Tags: clipboard, sensitive-data, clipboarddata

I'm using the Quicksilver clipboard history plugin to record the last 15 items.

The problem is i sometimes need to copy/paste passwords or other sensitive data (from 1Password for example) and i was wondering if there was a way to not log this type of data.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Quicksilver and/or Alfred would need to be aware of where those clips came from, i.e. from 1Password, etc, in order to exclude them.

1Password itself has an option to remove the clipboard data after a certain period of time (90 seconds by default, I believe).

I don't think there's an easy automated way to do what you want though.

Comment: Ok. I thought i was maybe possible not to trigger the clipboard plugin by using some sort of key combination.
Thanks for you reply

Answer (score 0):

There is a voluntary methodology for password programs to notify clipboard monitors to NOT capture the data.  If your clipboard monitor and the password program both implemented it, then you would not have passwords being captured.  I suspect that one or both of them do not use this system, which is described here:
http://www.clipboardextender.com/developing-clipboard-aware-programs-for-windows/ignoring-clipboard-updates-with-the-cf_clipboard_viewer_ignore-clipboard-format
Basically, the password program adds a private clipboard format called CF_CLIPBOARD_VIEWER_IGNORE, and the clipboard monitoring program looks for that and treats it as a "do not capture this sensitive stuff" flag.  It works, but only if both parties use it.
I wrote the article above over 10 years ago, hoping that it would be in widespread use by now. Alas, it has not, but it HAS been implemented by several password managers, and several leading clipboard managers besides my own.

Answer (score 0):

In Quicksilver's preferences for the Clipboard plugin, you can specify a list of applications to ignore.